# (React / CSS) the width of <ul> is not fitting the width of <li> when <li>'s animation updating the width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am current implementing a typing animation in React. The `li` has an animation that changes its width from `0px` to `100%` recursively. However, when `li`'s width changes, the `ul` does fit the width of the `li`, leaving a empty space in the text area. I want the wrapper shrink together with the `li` animation.

Perhaps the root cause of the issue is because I directly mutated the `li` children using `ref.current.contentText`, but I am not sure.

I have created the demo for visualization, the empty space is highlighted in blue:

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-breeze-hq7d6e?file=/src/styles.css

Has anyone got an idea what is wrong with my code, and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my approach from css to javascript to avoid the issue. But feel free to leave a comment if you know what is going on with the css issue. Thanks

```
const Test = () => {

    const textOptions = ['Military Personnel', 'Software Developer', 'Construction Worker', 'Medical Professional'];
    const dynamicRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        function changeText() {
            let optionIndex = 0;
            let charIndex = 0;
            let increment = true;

            setInterval(() => {
                if (dynamicRef.current) {
                    dynamicRef.current.textContent = textOptions[optionIndex].slice(0, charIndex);

                    if (charIndex === textOptions[optionIndex].length) {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            increment = false;
                        }, 500);
                    } else if (charIndex <= 0) {
                        optionIndex++;
                        increment = true;
                    }

                    if (increment) {
                        charIndex++;
                    } else {
                        charIndex--;
                    }

                    if (optionIndex > textOptions.length - 1) {
                        optionIndex = 0;
                    }

                }
            }, 100)
        }
        changeText();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className='test'>
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <p>I am</p>
                <p ref={dynamicRef}></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```